# Make jquery plugin work on multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking to buil a jquery plugin that will transform a link to a hidden form and fill some fields.
The form will be used to post json data to a method in the back end.
The class starts the work and I can set custom settings. The issue is when I have more than one export needed on each page the settings are only using the last iteration.
See below for more clarification.

Init the plugin with the class and add the processing link

```
$(".export-csv").exportCSV({
    link: '{$base_url}ajax/export-csv'
});
```

Here I have two links for exporting data.
I pass through the title and data (smarty templating system)

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="export-csv"
        data-title='Landlords'
        data-data='{$landlords_json}'>Export Landlords (CSV)</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="export-csv"
        data-title='Buyers'
        data-data='{$buyers_json}'>Export Buyers (CSV)</a>
</li>
```

When I click either button it will give me the buyers export as it was latest in the loop.
The forms are showing the correct data when I inspect the page. It must be the settings.title and settings.data that are getting caught.
I can see its due to the position in the loop but I am unsure how to fix this.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.exportCSV = function ( options ) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            title: null,
            data: null,
            link: '/',
            link_text: 'Export (CSV)',
        }, options);

        return $(this).each( function () {
            settings.title = $(this).data('title');
            settings.data = JSON.stringify( $(this).data('data') );

            var hidden_form = "<form id='" + settings.title.toLowerCase() + "-export-csv' action='" + settings.link + "' method='POST' style='display: none;'>" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='title' value='" + settings.title + "'>" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='data' value='" + settings.data + "'>" +
                "</form>";
            $(this).append(hidden_form);

            $(this).on('click', function () {
                console.log( $(this) );
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#' + settings.title.toLowerCase() + '-export-csv').submit();
            });
        });
    }

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Try by moving your settings variable declaration inside the each loop function.

Comment: @Sami yes that did the trick. I was thinking there should be a way to set the defaults once then overwrite them but this works. Thanks